# Make API Call synchronous

Tags: ios, json

I have the following code and I would like to make it synchronous. The problem I am having is that while my api is called my program continues on and the nil data values are passed in the mean time. Thank you for all the help in advance. \

{- (IBAction)Make_Payment:(id)sender {

```
NSString *temp2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\n  \"partner_key\": \"%@\",\n  \"auth_token\": \"QaU9QcFZ6xE7aiRRBge0wZ4p6E01GEbl\",\n  \"payment_account_id\": \"%@\",\n  \"card_number\": \"%@\",\n  \"card_exp_date\": \"%@\",\n  \"amount\": \"%@\",\n  \"memo\": \"%@\",\n  \"recipient\": {\n    \"email\": \"%@\",\n    \"mobile_phone\": \"%@\"\n  }\n}",[Partner_Key text], [Payment_Account_ID text], [Card_Number text], [Card_Exp_Date text], [Amount text],[Memo text], [Recipient_Email text], [Recipient_Phone_Number text]];

NSLog(temp2);

NSNumber *errorCode    = nil;
NSString *errorMessage = nil;
NSString *guid1         = nil;
NSString *exponent     = nil;
NSString *modulus      = nil;

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://cert.payzur.com/payzurservices.svc/payment/send/initiate"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:[temp2 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];




NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL] completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error) {
    if(error && failure)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            failure(error);
        });
    }
    else if(success)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            success(data);
        });
    }

}] resume];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                        completionHandler:
                              ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                  if (error) {
                                      // Handle error...
                                      return;
                                  }

                                  if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
                                      NSLog(@"Response HTTP Status code: %ld\n", (long)[(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode]);
                                      NSLog(@"Response HTTP Headers:\n%@\n", [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields]);
                                  }

                                  NSString* body = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                  NSLog(@"Response Body:\n%@\n", body);

                                  NSError *error1;
                                  NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
                                  NSLog(@"res: \n%@", res);

                                  if (res) {
                                      NSString *errorCode    = res[@"error_code"];
                                      NSString *errorMessage = res[@"error_message"];
                                      NSString *guid1         = res[@"guid"];
                                      NSString *exponent     = res[@"exponent"];
                                      NSString *modulus      = res[@"modulus"];

                                  NSLog(@"errorCode: %@\nerrorMessage: %@\nguid: %@\nexponent: %@\nmodulus: %@", errorCode, errorMessage, guid1, exponent, modulus);


                                  }
                                  else {
                                      NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                                  }


                              }];
[task resume];
```

}

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize this was the same issue from the other question so I deleted my answer since it was the same as my comment there.

Comment: Completely, understand!

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the completion block of NSURLSession.
The activities you want to perform, just perform them in the completion block. Make sure that whenever you are performing some UI tasks in NSURLSession's completion block, perform them on the main thread.

```
-(void)sendRequestForURL:(NSString*)urlString Success:(void(^)(NSData *data))success Failure: (void(^)(NSError *error))failure
    {
        NSURLSession *session=[NSURLSession sharedSession];
        [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error) {
            if(error && failure)
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    failure(error);
                });
            }
            else if(success)
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                     success(data);
                });
            }

        }] resume];
    }
```

Comment: I have updated what you told me to add in my code but for some reason, I'm getting multiple errors, may you can tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: First thing, you are making the web service call from the controller itself. Which is a very bad design. Create a separate class which is responsible for the web service call. Make use of that class to call a web service. Now what errors you are getting?

Comment: I updated the code in my answer with what you told me to add. And then errors I get is incompatible pointer types sending 'NSURL to parameter of type NSString' also, use of undeclared identifier failure, implicit declaration of failure is invalid in c99, use of undeclared indentifier success did you mean access and implicit declaration of function success is invalid in c99.

Comment: Dude, I hope you haven't copied the code as it is. The code was just an example. So instead of success and failure, you write your own code there.